# Can I use a SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter with a javax.servlet.Filter?

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, servlet-filters, jespa

I would like to set up a webservice endpoint using Spring's [`SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter.html) for ease of use, but I also need to protect the webservice using a subclass of Jespa's [`HttpSecurityFilter`](http://www.ioplex.com/d/jespa/api/jespa/http/HttpSecurityFilter.html)

I suspect this does not work out of the box as `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter` is using a separate HTTP server to the host webapp containing the filter - how should I accomplish this?

I have a class annotated with [`@WebService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) and in my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter"
        p:baseAddress="http://localhost:9581/"/>
```

Comment: The Jespa HttpSecurityService requires a javax.servlet implementation to function. Although it's requirements are minimal. The only vaguely difficult part would be implementing HttpSession. Jespa needs to be able to set/get a byte[] array in the HttpSession and have it actually persist correctly. Otherwise, the Servlet implementation requirements for the HSS to function are simple. Note that the Jespa HttpSecurityFilter is just a Filter wrapper around the HttpSecurityService. The HttpSecurityService does not implement javax.servlet.Filter (although it very much looks like one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a couple of alternative ways to host the endpoint within the same HTTP server (behind the filter)

Either using JAX-WS [WSSpringServlet](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) and registering my `@WebService` beans via the `wss:binding` xml tag under the `http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet` namespace, or my preferred option, as JAX-WS Spring integration has Maven dependencies on Spring 2, using [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html).